# Alterando connectionStrings do app.config fisicamente em runtime

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Em meu app.config tenho as seguintes linhas de código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ControleBD"
            connectionString="Data Source=SERVIDOR\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Controle;User ID=Adminx;Password=123456"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Como faço para alterar o valor da connectionString fisicamente em runtime?

Answer (score 2):

Se quiser alterar a `connection string` durante o runtime:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var connectionString = (ConnectionStringsSection) config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
connectionString.ConnectionStrings["ControleBD"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=NewSource;Initial Catalog=NewCatalog;UID=NewUser;password=NewPassword";
config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

De notar que o código atrás apenas altera a `connection string` em memória, isto é o ficheiro `app.config` não será alterado.

Comment: Já fiz isso, mas como você falou, ele só é alterado em memória. Gostaria de alterar fisicamente.

Answer (score 1):

A forma que altero a ConnectionString fisicamente no web.config é a seguinte:

```
Configuration webConfigApp = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
webConfigApp.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=NewSource;Initial Catalog=NewCatalog;UID=NewUser;password=NewPassword";
webConfigApp.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var connectionString = (ConnectionStringsSection) config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
connectionString.ConnectionStrings["ControleBD"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=NewSource;Initial Catalog=NewCatalog;UID=NewUser;password=NewPassword";
config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

usei este código, mas não está apenas atualizando em memória, ele está jogando para o arquivo, precisava de um código para alterar apenas em memória, alguém sabe?

Answer (score -2):

Você pode alterar o arquivo fisicamente (XML), apenas altere aonde precisa, não existe uma forma pronta para isso.

Caso você precise das modificações em memória após alteração física vai ser preciso recarregar ou setar em memória ao mesmo tempo que fisicamente.

Comment: existe uma maneira pronta sim

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo!!!